# RecyclerView inside ScrollView - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

Here is my xml code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <!-- Header -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <!-- Some views here -->

        </RelativeLayout>
        
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When the user touches the RecyclerView and scrolls, I hide the header gradually with the pace that the user scrolls using a scroll listener on the RecyclerView like this:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(int dy)
{ 
    if (dy < headerHeight)
    {
        scrollView.setScrollY(dy);
    } 
}
```

The problem is that, while the header is hiding and I scroll in a slow manner, there is some serious flickering problem. The view goes up and down like crazy. This behavior stops when dy > headerHeight.

I am guessing that because the position of the whole RecyclerView changes when the ScrollView scrolls, that's the root reason of the problem. How can I fix this and achieve a smooth scrolling?

Comment: You should probably be using a NestedScrollView when you have two scrolling elements

Comment: @tyczj I have already tried it, but there wasn't any difference.

Comment: May be you should look at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967796/12660050

Comment: Add recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); and use NestedScrollView.

Comment: I can't use recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); because then I have to expand the RecyclerView to it's whole length and lose the basic functionality of RecyclerViews. My list is really long.

Comment: Can you show a gif to the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is awful. You don't need all those nested views. Read this article for example: https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b. Delete all those unnecessary views and keep only recycler view with root relative layout for example and your problem should disapear.

Comment: I have already thought about this approach. RecyclerView's which have items with different heights have performance issues.

Comment: Actually this approach was really helpful and I wanted to thank you. It's the closest thing I found so far to the solution I was looking for.